# persist/update collection of data into database using hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am newbie to Hibernate framework and I am curious about the way persist and update work.

Currently in my project when I would like to persist or update collection of data into database, I am doing it one by one via looping method. For instance,

```
    public persistData(){
       List<Person> personList = new ArrayList<>();
       for(Person person : personList){
            session.persist(person);
       }
    }
```

Is it possible to, for example,

```
    session.persist(personList);
```

Or there is anyway else I can persist/update collection of data at once without looping?

Editted:
I have found Hibernate Batch Processing in 
[How to insert multiple rows into database using hibernate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20458401/how-to-insert-multiple-rows-into-database-using-hibernate)
and [Best way to insert a good amount of records in hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4587608/best-way-to-insert-a-good-amount-of-records-in-hibernate)

I am developing generic class for persist/update/delete data with hibernate, should I provide the method with

```
    public void (List<T> addedItemList)
```

or

```
    public void (T addedItem)
```

For my understanding, bulk persist should be done with large amount of transactions right? If some times there is only 1 or 2 objects to be persisted, is batch processing still appropriate?

Comment: You might start with reading the documentation: http://hibernate.org/orm/ (picking the version you use).

Comment: AFAIK there is no bulk update method. Wrap your `for` loop in a transaction and committing it at the end of the method will be efficient. If you've large number of rows use [batch inserting](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/batch.html#batch-inserts)

Answer (score 0):

The main point here is to begin the transaction, persist all, and then commit.  Try not using the @Transaction since you are doing it with the code.

```
                EntityManager em = entityManagerProvider.get();
//                em.clear();//remove this if caching is necessary
                em.getTransaction().begin();
                for(buildings b:buildingsArray) {
                     em.persist(b);
                }
                em.getTransaction().commit();
```